# Tag a Docker image in Google Container Registry with additional tag via command line

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to tag a Docker image sitting in Google Container Registry but am not having any luck. If the image were sitting on my local machine, i could do something like:

`docker tag my-image:existing-tag my-image:new-tag`

This would result in a second tag for my image. However, in Google Container Registry, I cannot simply use the `gcloud` wrapper to do so. For example:

`gcloud docker -- tag gcr.io/my-project/my-image:existing-tag gcr.io/my-project/my-image:new-tag`

This command will not work because even though I am running with `gcloud`, I get the following response:

`Error response from daemon: no such id gcr.io/my-project/my-image:existing-tag`

Is what I am attempting possible, and how would one accomplish it?

Comment: Using the Docker client (and `gcloud docker`), you need to `pull` an image to your local machine, `tag` it, then `push` the newly tagged image. Alternately, you can use `gcloud container images add-tag`, as you've discovered :)

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting, I discovered I needed to update to the latest `gcloud` and then could run `gcloud container images add-tag`. Problem solved.